# How to stop multicast packets in python from looping back to its own self when using the same port number for receiving and transmitting?

Tags: python, sockets

I’m building a python script that responds to mDNS queries. For example if I ping test.local or anything else (.local) a get an IP address e.g. 127.0.0.1. Basically this script spoofs mDNS queries.

The script listens on port 5353. It also transmits on that port as well.

The script also receives mDNS packets from the multicast address 224.0.0.251. It also responds to the same multicast as it receives.

When the script is executed it waits for an mDNS query. Once an mDNS query has reached the python script it responds with an mDNS packet containg an IP address (response packet), after that the script terminates with error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mdns.py", line 113, in <module>
    data, addr = udps.recvfrom(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 10040]
```

A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.
From what I gather there is a loop that is causing the mDNS response packets to not just transmit to the outside but also to transmit to the script. Therefore causing a loop.

What I’m trying to figure out is how I can stop this looping to the script its self all together.

Comment: Maybe explain how you gather there is a loop?  Even if there are loops one `recvfrom()` should return one packet, not a concatenation of a growing number of packets.